# Load XML once and access it in all views in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, global-variables, view

I have a three different views in my application. There is one local xml file to be loaded whenever the application is launched. And this xml is accessed by all the three views.

I wrote a function to load the file inside the main view (onCreationComplete). However, first of all, it's not accessible in the other two views and second, whenever the main view is poped it executes the onCreationComplete method and load the file over and over.

What i need is:

```
1. load the xml only when the application is launched // once
2. access the file in all views
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can send the xml into your views using the "data" argument of navigator.pushView(SomeView , someData );

This will require some structuring, though.

I suggest you

1. Write a small controller, which will load your xml and stores it.
2. Hold a reference of this controller in you MainApp.mxml or whereever you manage your view changes.
3. pass the xml property to your view when it's created (e.g by navigator.pushView() );
4. Override the data setter in your view.

   ```
   var xml:XML ;

   override set data(value:Object):void
   {
    xml = value as XML;
    super.data = value;
   }
   ```
5. Wait until your view is ready to use (e.g. listen to the creationComplete - Event). You can now use your xml data.